# Find the files that doesn't have a string or having it but commented out

Tags: bash, grep

Below are the sample files in which I am looking for the files that doesnt have the word "DEF" or is commented out if exists.

```
cat text.txt_1
ABC
DEF
GHI

cat text.txt_2
ABC
#DEF
GHI

cat text.txt_3
ABC
GHI
```

I am trying to do something like this `grep -Lr "DEF" . || grep -iwr "DEF" . | grep "^#"` but it is not working

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Something on lines of `grep "^[^#]*DEF"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `gnu grep` then use:

```
grep -zvlr '^[^#]*DEF'
```

Otherwise, you can use `awk` with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name 'text.*' -exec awk '/^[^#]*DEF/{p=1} END{if (!p) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Comment: Can you please tell me.. how to awk case insensitive here?

Comment: Using gnu awk you can use: `find . -type f -name 'text.*' -exec awk -v IGNORECASE=1 '/^[^#]*DEF/{p=1} END{if (!p) print FILENAME}' {} \;`

Comment: Thank you @anubhava